# How to pull images from Azure Container Registry when using K3s?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-container-registry, k3s

In production we use Azure Container Registry and AKS. For development, we have K3s on our dev server (on-prem). Is it possible for K3s to pull images from a private registry such as Azure Container Registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is Yes, even if the Azure Container Registry is a private registry, but if you have the username and password with the right permissions, then you can pull the image in it via the username and password. You can take a look at the steps in [Azure Container Registry authentication with service principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal).

Comment: Thanks! It seems I was using my ACR account passwd instead of the service principal password.